# How to set selection for a table in Numbers?

Tags: python, iwork, sourceforge-appscript, py-appscript

How do you set the selection for a table in Numbers using `py-appscript`?

This seems like it should be really simple to do but the solution is frustratingly evasive. I can get the current selection:

```
 current_table.selection_range
```

and I can get its cells:

```
  current_table.selection_range.cells()
```

but trying to `set()` either of them gets an angry `appscript` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like something like this works:

```
>>> current_table.selection_range.set(to=current_table.ranges[u'B3:C10'])
```

Note, looking at `Number's` script dictionary in `AppleScript Editor` or with `ASDictionary`, the property `selection_range` is defined as class `range`.  So that's a clue that you need to come up with a reference of type `range` to set it.

Comment: Thanks again Ned. You are really saving my ass today :) I was afraid I might not find anyone on SO who knew about `appscript` since it is such a specialized technology. The whole reference / element system takes some getting used to..

Comment: And thanks for the extra advice too. I was going to ask you where you get your information and I am presuming from this note that you just use the `ASDictionary`'s and experience?

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the points.  Yes, it does take some getting used to and, unfortunately, not all scriptable apps are as well-behaved as Numbers seems to be.  Fortunately, the father of appscript, has, is a wonderful resource and he is known to hang out on SO as well as on the Python Mac SIG mailing list: http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.apple

Comment: A combination of ASDictionary, the standard AppleScript Editor.app, trying snippets in a Python interpreter, the py-appscript docs, web searches, and a bit of experience. The biggest problem, IMO, with scriptable apps is lack of consistency: there's no way to know for sure how a particular app's object model really works without exploring it and sometimes the waters are really murky.